# How can I show different spinner for api request?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I use React and Redux. I want to show a spinner for each request individually. Let's say I have a dashboard with multiple widgets and they all have a different api call.

Using one isLoading inside state isn't enough.

Should I really do something like isLoadingWidget1, isLoadingWidget2, isLoadingWidget3,...?

Is there a better way to do it? I don't want to have isLoadingXXX multiple times in state.

My current reducer

```
const initialState = {
    posts: [],
    isLoading: false,
    isLoadingWidget1: ????
};


export default ( state = questionReducerDefaultState, action ) => {
    switch ( action.type ) {
        case SET_LOADING: 
            return {
                ...state,
                isLoading: true
            };

        case CLEAR_LOADING:
            return {
                ...state,
                isLoading: false
            };

        case GET_POSTS:
            return {
                ...state,
                posts: action.payload
            };

        default:
            return state;
    };
};
```

My current action

```
export const startGetPosts = () => {
    return ( dispatch ) => {
        dispatch( setLoading() );

        return axios.get( '/api/posts' ).then( ( res ) => {
            dispatch({
                type: GET_POSTS,
                payload: res.data
            });

            dispatch( clearLoading() );
        }).catch( ( err ) => {
            console.log( err );
        });
    };
};
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply add:

```
const initialState = {
    posts: [],
    isLoading: false,
    widget: 0
};

export default ( state = questionReducerDefaultState, action ) => {
    switch ( action.type ) {
        case SET_LOADING: 
            return {
                ...state,
                isLoading: true,
                widget: action.widget
            };
        //...
    };
};
```

and you can call it as

```
dispatch({
    type: SET_LOADING,
    widget: 1
})
```

and then based on widget number you will show the current widget

Comment: This was along the lines of what I was thinking, and should work fine unless multiple widgets are loading at the same time.

Comment: @TonyAbrams in case of that you can make that `widget` an array